# Connecting faces

Tags: modeling

I've made this random building in which I'd like to have the corners stick out like support "pillars". As I extruded on the x and y axis, I'm now in doubt about how to connect these into a a single support pillar (onnect in the middle to create a square)

This is what it looks like:

[image]

But this is what I want (All the way down the pillar ofc):

[image]

Could anyone lend me a hand to a nice solution? :)

Comment: Should the exhisting geometry remain inside of newly created pillar ? Or is it acceptable to delete exhisting faces (which will become manifold otherwise) while creating new geometry ? In first case you can extrude and grab with snapping, in second probably using Bridge Edge Loops may help, again with snapping after finishing for precision.

Comment: @MrZak I'm not sure what you mean? I made it working by deleting the inner faces (where the new part of the pillar needs to be connected), combine the to outer vertices (to create a triangle), the subdivide the edge that it makes, and look and the x-y position of the other vertices to make them match correctly. Then combine all 4 vertices to create a face. Hard to explain :) If you have a quick way to do this, please explain :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how I'd do this:

First delete the faces of one wall your original structure.
[image: 1st]

Then select the faces of the opposite wall and extrude them till the outer edge reconstructs the shape you want.
[image: Part 2]

If you find it difficult to align the verts precisely, you can snap the 3D cursor to a vertex on the outer edge by selecting this vertex and <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> --> Cursor to Selected.
Then select the extruded faces and align them with that vertex by changing the pivot point to 3D cursor <kbd>.</kbd>, then scaling to 0 on the relevant axis (X in the example shown here): <kbd>S</kbd> --> <kbd>X</kbd> --> <kbd>0</kbd>.

[image: Part 2.5]

Now you need to delete the useless faces in between, so select and delete them or they will be non-manifold in the final mesh:
[image: Part 3]

And finally, select all your vertices and remove doubles <kbd>W</kbd> --> Remove Doubles, to merge all the duplicate vertices created by the extrusion.

[image: Remove Doubles]

Comment: I actually managed to find another way, but this seems to be the fastest and most simple solution. Appreciate your answer.

Comment: You could select stack of faces of one pillar and just extrude it with snapping turned on; this would allow to skip steps with scaling to 3D Cursor. You can use `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Shift`+`M` to select and then delete non-manifold geometry (not in Face selection mode).